# Where do I put javascript functions in grails to have it accessible?

Tags: javascript, grails

I have a script to check/uncheck all boxes on a form in a grails application that I am trying to call. I included the function (in `<g:javascript>` tags) in the head section of the page, and even added an alert before declaring the function to make sure the code block was being processed (it worked), but when I hit my check/uncheck all button, firebug tells me that it can't find the symbol; and looking at the source code, the function doesn't seem to be present. Where do I put this to get grails to include this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your web-app/js library, naming it yourScript.js

You include them in your your page by

```
<g:javascript library="yourScript"/>
```

Notice the lack of .js in the  tag

Comment: You'd recommend this rather than just trying to put the script into the page inline? It was my understanding you could do either...

Comment: Ah, sorry. Missed the point... If you use Prototype, make this function: 
    Event.observe(document,'dom:loaded',function() { 
     //do init stuffhere 
    }); 
Because if you put onclick events before the html, it will not register as the DOM is not yet established.